# Restoring a Unicode MySQL database in XAMPP Windows 7

Tags: mysql, drupal, unicode, xampp

I have a backup of a Drupal site in raw SQL format. Three months before, I changed my host. I restored the backup in the new host through the command line:

```
mysql -u username -ppasswd dbname < backup.sql
```

The process worked perfect and my site is running smoothly till now.

But recently I tried to make a local copy of that site in my Win7 XAMPP.

I used the same restoring process in XAMPP shell but no success. While restoring, it stops with the `DUPLICATE ENTRY IN PRIMARY` error.

Using `--force` switch, I get several hundred such duplicate entry errors.

When finished, the Unicode characters in body (post body and comment body) are OK but the titles, username etc are destroyed.

I tried it with `no charset` option, `latin1` option, `utf8` option but all failed.

The same backup works fine in my live server but can not restore it in local XAMPP.

Kindly help.

Comment: Two things I want to say. First; My Win 7 is a virtual machine in vmware. Physically I use XP But the recent XAMPP do not supports XP. Another is I guess, the characters tied with links are creating problem (ie the title, username etc.)

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: Let's see the hex of some of the "Unicode characters".

Comment: @Rick@ my live server version is Apache Version  2.4.12
PHP Version  5.5.22
MySQL Version  5.5.42-cll
Architecture  x86_64
Operating System  linux
---- Restoring is perfect here. /// My XAMPP machine •Server version: 5.6.21 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
•Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.19

Comment: Ouch.  `SELECT HEX('ডলি” কে যে ভা]')` is `E0A6A1E0A6B2E0A6BFE2809D20E0A695E0A78720E0A6AFE0A78720E0A6ADE0A6BE5D`.  In a typical error case, I would expect `à¦¡à¦²à¦¿â€ à¦•à§‡ à¦¯à§‡ à¦­à¦¾]`, not `ÔÇ£ÓªíÓª?`.  In fact, I can't figure where `ÔÇ£ÓªíÓª?` comes from.

Comment: You need to specify utf8 in multiple places -- the connection to MySQL, the table definition, the meta tag in html, etc.

Comment: @Rick@ I have an update. After clearing cache, all unicode texts are gone. Probably the body was OK from cache. In the backup file, all charset was utf8. I replaced all of them to latine1. Created the database in utf format. But no result. When I open that backup in text editor, I can clearly see the texts. Where to set the meta tags? Guide me please.

Comment: What cache did you clear?  (A "cache" should never cause bad data.)  Do not use latin1; you need utf8.  `SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- to see if the _columns_ are utf8.

Comment: cleares site cache. utf and latin gives same result. columns are utf8 now.

Comment: See if you can get the HEX from the table now.

Comment: D3AAA9D3BAFCD3AABCD3BAECD3AA3FD3AAF120D3AAC2D3BAFC... is an username HEX. HEX of Admin = 61646D696E

Comment: Ouch.  ('Admin' is fine; the other is a mess.)  Have you ever used anything other than latin1 or utf8?  Have you used any utf8 functions in PHP?  Is there anything buried in Drupal that is relevant.  (I have a program that tries hundreds of conversions -- none could convert your Bengali to/from anything like the D3AA...)  I'll need some extra clue to solve this riddle.

Comment: There in nothing in php or drupal. I see directly in the database using phpMyAdmin. Here is another strange update. I copied some INSERT statement from my backup file into the query window of phpMyAdmin and it inserts everything perfect. But importing through mysql command line does not work. Any idea?